# Leaflet: How to zoom keeping a place fixed?

Tags: leaflet

Given the map below, I would like to zoom in/move from the outer view to the inner view, keeping the top left corner exactly the same.

Leaflet seems to allow only to move to a centre, not a top left corner and zoom level.
I know the current zoom level, bounds and centre and the new zoom level and desired top left corner.
How can I calculate the pink X?
Alternatively, if there's another way to change to the new view, how can I do it?

[image: Example map]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need for calculating the center for such a situation (and this is, in fact, a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)); it seems you missed the [`setZoomAround` method of `L.Map`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#map-setzoomaround), which does exactly what you wanted to do in the first place:

> `setZoomAround(<LatLng> latlng, <Number> zoom, <Zoom options> options)`
>
> Zooms the map while keeping a specified geographical point on the map stationary (e.g. used internally for scroll zoom and double-click zoom).

> `setZoomAround(<Point> offset, <Number> zoom, <Zoom options> options)`
>
> Zooms the map while keeping a specified pixel on the map (relative to the top-left corner) stationary.

Either get the northwest corner of the map bounds and call `setZoomAround` with that, like...

```
map.setZoomAround( map.getBounds().getNorthWest(), newZoomLevel );
```

... or wrap the desired fixed pixel coordinate in a `L.Point`, which for the top-left corner of the map is `[0, 0]`, like...

```
map.setZoomAround( L.point([0, 0]), newZoomLevel );
```

Comment: Thanks a lot - when reading the docs, I hadn't considered that the stationary point could be the north-western corner!

Comment: how do i keep the map centered around a group of markers as the map container is enlarged with a transition? btw, the markers are variables so i cant hard code coordinates